# Some tiff not included on a vrt index

Tags: raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, vrt, gdalbuildvrt

I have some tiff files and I'm trying to generate a vrt index with gdal tool, gdalbuildvrt.

I run this command:

```
gdalbuildvrt orto_index.vrt -srcnodata "0 0 0" -vrtnodata "0 0 0" *.tif
```

and throws the next warning:

```
Warning 6: gdalbuildvrt does not support rotated geo transforms.
Skipping 2335-C.tif
```

So there are some tiff that are skipped.

If we compare the information about a skipped file with another that it has not skipped, we could see the next difference:

In the skipped file, we can see the next line:

```
GeoTransform =
  345770.7884398972, 0.6000000238418568, 3.473043927400512e-15
  6139634.558238117, 1.757016748640284e-14, -0.6000000238417672
```

In the non skipped file, the other one:

```
Origin = (223499.236031105130678,6213152.835421450436115)
Pixel Size = (0.600000023841858,-0.600000023841858)
```

How can I make to get a vrt file including all files, I mean, without skip some files?

Answer (score 1):

The key line is

> Warning 6: gdalbuildvrt does not support rotated geo transforms.
>   Skipping 2335-C.tif

You need to convert the tiffs that have rotated geo transforms to not have them. I suspect that it's a projection issue but without more knowledge of the history of your files can't be sure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think you're right but I don't have the original tiles, the tiles that I have, have already been rotated and I don't know how to return back and disable this rotation.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to convert that problematic tiff with gdalwarp. The command is like

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -co tiled=yes -dstnodata 0 2335-C.tif 2335-C-warped.tif
```

Remove the original tif from the directory, rename the warped file if you wish and gdalbuildvrt should be successful.

Comment: note that the proper option is "-dstnodata" NOT "-dstnodate"