# Display multiple ASCII (xyz) files in QGIS

Tags: dem, ascii, xyz

I am new to QGIS and I am trying to import more than 700 xyz (it is the same as ASCII?) files into the map so I can get a digital elevation model and then get the average elevation for some small polygons. I can simply import individual xyz file but importing more at once doesn't work for me?

I would like to make something such as a virtual raster catalog but I get:

> Warning 6: gdalbuildvrt does not support positive NS resolution.

My files look like this: (they have no headers)

```
383000.0  97000.0   83.30
383005.0  97000.0   82.80
383010.0  97000.0   82.70...
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Ivan! Perhaps these posts might help: [How do you import simple xyz in QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73804/how-do-you-import-simple-xyz-in-qgis); and [Create a Raster file out of a ASCII grid file?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115024/create-a-raster-file-out-of-a-ascii-grid-file)

Comment: Does your data fulfill the ordering rules from http://www.gdal.org/frmt_xyz.html and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115024/create-a-raster-file-out-of-a-ascii-grid-file? If yes, use gdal_transform -of VRT first, then gdalbuildvrt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64471/some-tiff-not-included-on-a-vrt-index. See also https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5601 for a workaround.